# Run exe with admin perms in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, execute

I want to start an exe-file as admin with node. Tried something like this, but this dont want to work:

```
exec('runas /user:Administrator "app.exe"', function(err, data) {  
                        console.log(err)                       
});
```

Im always getting this error: `Error: Command failed: runas /user:Administrator "app.exe"`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) of `runas` you should include the ComputerName like this:

```
If you want to use the Administrator account on your computer, for the /user: parameter, type one of the following:

**/user:<**AdministratorAccountName>@<ComputerName>

**/user:<ComputerName>\<**AdministratorAccountName>    <----- here
```